# How to map user IDs on an NFS share?

Tags: linux, mount, nfs

I have succesfully mounted an NFS share from my remote machine to my local. However, the files I want to edit on the remote machine are all owned by `root`.

How can I mount my NFS drive so that my local user can edit these files?

I tried the `idmap.conf` file, but I couldn't quite get if I should edit that on the local or remote machine and which services I should restart (again, local or remote) to have any affect.

From the past, I remember the `uid=X,gid=X` options to do something like this, but I now get this error on those:

```
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified
```

I am using Fedora 34 as local and CentOS 7.6 remote.

Comment: `uid=` is from SMB, I think - looking for the same as you with NFSv3, still confused :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With all file-based network filesystems, file permissions are enforced *by the server.* What `ls -l` says you can do with a file doesn't necessarily have to match what you can actually do with that file.

For example, if you were using SMB or SSHFS and authenticated to the server as "bart", you would only have the privileges of the user "bart" on the server – it doesn't matter what `ls -l` reports, it doesn't matter if you are root on the local system; the local `uid=` option wouldn't have any effect on what your SSHFS account is allowed to do server-side.

But unlike SSHFS (which uses one connection and one set of credentials), NFS was originally designed to be a "system-wide" feature where the same mount could be used by various different users, each with their own privileges – and it was designed to work in homogenous environments together with NIS/YP, a system that ensured that the same accounts had the same UIDs on every machine. Most NFS client features (or lack thereof) still reflect that design.

So with this in mind, UIDs have two completely different and independent usages in NFS: ownership data reported by server and authentication credentials reported by client.

- Ownership information *reported by server* (such as data in `ls -l`) is handled as part of NFS itself.

  (This is where options like `uid=` would be relevant, but the Linux NFS client doesn't have them, although a few other filesystems do.)

  In NFSv4, ownership information can be translated using "idmap": the server converts the UID into a username@domain, the client converts that username back to its local UID. Make sure both sides use the same idmap domain (as reported by `nfsidmap -d`) – if it differs, set it manually via /etc/idmap.conf. However, this doesn't really let you *do* anything with that file – it's mostly just visual.

  In NFSv3, only a numeric UID can be reported and there is no facility for mapping it – the client always sees the UID that's stored on the server.
- However, actual *effective* privileges rely on information *reported by client* as they are enforced server-side, not only client-side. This is handled at SunRPC level, so there's no relationship with NFS versions.

  Due to the NFS client being designed to be multi-user, its default authentication mechanism is to simply report the accessing user's UID to the server. So if you export and mount the NFS share with `sec=sys` (the default), then the client always reports your real UID to the server, and the server trusts it without any verification.

  Unfortunately, while in theory UIDs *could* be mapped here before reporting them to the server, there is no such feature in the Linux NFS client at all, and it always reports your real UID.

  To solve this, you would need to either synchronize your account's UID across all systems, or use Kerberos authentication via `sec=krb5`. This requires having a Kerberos KDC server set up.

So in short,

0. Make sure you're using NFSv4. Run `mount` or `findmnt -u` to see what version is being selected.
1. Run `nfsidmap -d` and verify that both systems use the same idmap domain. This is by default guessed from the system's FQDN (`hostname -f`) but it can also be set in `/etc/idmapd.conf`. This value doesn't need to be a real DNS domain, just an arbitrary string. This should fix the owner shown by `ls`.
2. Strongly consider setting up Kerberos, running a KDC on your server (it could be the same server or a different one), and switching NFS to `sec=krb5`. (Especially if you are using NFS over the Internet!)

   You do not need any complex additional components like LDAP or Active Directory or IPA – just the fairly small "krb5kdc" daemon.

   (The same Kerberos can also be used for SSH authentication via "GSSAPIAuthentication", not just for NFS.)
3. If that's not an option, then you will need to change your account's UID on one system to match the other. It's usually just a matter of logging in as root and doing `usermod -u` (which also chowns the entire home directory).

Comment: `just a matter of logging in as root and doing usermod -u`?  THEN finding and changing the owner UID of every relevant file on the system!

Answer (score 2):

The best way to solve this is by using kerberos as mentioned before.

As an alternative to kerberos, on how you can achieve the same goal while using NFS4, considering you wanna do this for a few machines in your home.

Lets have in mind you are sharing the directory `/mnt/public`

1. exported it like:

```
/mnt/public 192.168.1.0/24(rw)
```

*The question mentions a way to map users, my understanding is the goal is have a way to cross-connect users access with a simple NFS shares. So I'm mapping groups instead of stand-alone users. The same logic can be used for users by using SUID instead of SGID*

2. We need a specific GID to be in all our devices

```
groupadd homeshare -g 27000
```

*The clients will also need the same GID, that means manually create a group with ID 27000 in all the clients.*

3. Create the public directory with GSID permissions:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/public
chmod g+s /mnt/public
chown :homeshare /mnt/public
```

*the public share must use group suid and be owned by the group you've just created*

As a plus define a password for the group in the clients.
Use `newgrp` to login on it.
With that, you don't need to add all the users to the group, only the ones who you shared the group password will have access.

Example:

```
gpasswd homeshare # define the password to the group
```

```
newgrp homeshare #login in the group using the password
```

Answer (score 1):

which user are you on your local machine? If you are root as well you should be able to edit these files. If your are root but you can not edit, have a look at your servers `/etc/exports` file as your root user might be squashed.

> root_squash
> Map requests from uid/gid 0 to the anonymous uid/gid. Note
> that this does not apply to any other uids or gids that
> might be equally sensitive, such as user bin or group
> staff.
>
> ```
>    no_root_squash
>           Turn off root squashing. This option is mainly useful for
>           diskless clients.
>
>    all_squash
>           Map all uids and gids to the anonymous user. Useful for
>           NFS-exported public FTP directories, news spool
>           directories, etc. The opposite option is no_all_squash,
>           which is the default setting.
>
>    anonuid and anongid
>           These options explicitly set the uid and gid of the
>           anonymous account.  This option is primarily useful for
>           PC/NFS clients, where you might want all requests appear
>           to be from one user. As an example, consider the export
>           entry for /home/joe in the example section below, which
>           maps all requests to uid 150 (which is supposedly that of
>           user joe).
> ```

Besides of this you should have same user IDs on remote and local machine. But there are no easy maintainable solutions for home use available.

In case you are *NOT* root there should be no way to archieve your goal as no one should be allowed to edit root's files on a remote machine!

Comment: I am not root. I am trying to move my SSHFS mount to NFS, because it is supposed to be faster. As `root` it works.

Comment: I am root on the server and this was a good option on a private home network. Thanks!